# mapping bit to integer in entity framework code first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, mapping, code-first

Working with code first, sqlserver and oracle.

My problem is:

I am having a SqlServer databases that contain tables where some fields are of type "bit".

Bit maps great to boolean when using entity framework code first.

I am trying to map "bit" fields to "Int32" property in c#.

When doing it i get an exception and the ColumnAttribute property doesnt seem to work in this case.

Is it possible to do this mapping?

(I know it sounds like extrange to wish to map bit to int32 instead of bool, but due to the limitations of Oracle regarding this area in code first i find it the most confortable way to have a common way to work with both databases).

Thanks!
libo

Comment: I don't know code first, but can't you do something with a 'case when' statment ? or a Cast ?

Comment: hey thomas, i dont think that i can do that. But thanks!